# Sending an image file via a HTTP get or post from SketchUp

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, image

So this particular programming conundrum I find myself in is quite a bit above my Ruby skills or any programming skills in general I guess.

Using an HTML (Post) form I am able to upload an image to my server side CGI script and from there I am able to take the data and then save it on my server. The bones of HTML required to do this, with all of the formatting fluff stripped away is essentially:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="logoupload.pl" method="post">
    <input name="imagefiletoupload" type="file">
    <input id="newlogo" name="imglogo" value="Update Logo">
    </form>
```

I really don’t understand how this works, other than the HTML form is able to select the file from the client end and then transfer it to my CGI/Perl file (logoupload.pl). On the server end I have some code in place that checks for errors, size etc… and then saves the file to the directory of my choosing.

This is all good, I can make this work.

Now what I want to try and do is within Ruby (given a path to an existing image file) send that image file to my same server side CGI script using some type of GET or POST call.

I have no idea how to do this.

My typical way I make calls to my server (or any other website address) is something like this:

```
 some_url = "http://design.medeek.com/resources/somescript.pl?var1=#{@Var1}&var2=#{Var2}&var3=#{@Var3}"
    
    require 'open-uri'

    begin
        open(some_url) { |io|
        url_response = io.read
            
        # Then parse the response with some code here or convert JSON to ruby array etc...
            
    }

    rescue StandardError => e
        UI.messagebox ("Unable to connect to server, action aborted.")
    end
```

How would I send an image via a URL call like this? Or is there a better way to do this?

So far I have no idea how to program this.

Comment: Just for reference the full Ruby language is embedded within SketchUp so my back end code that I am working with is Ruby.  My CGI scripting on the server end is Perl, but this shouldn't really matter in my opinion, so long as I send it a valid call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```rb
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://your-backend-url")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = url_response
request["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data"

http.request(request)
```